# Динамический layout блоков разного размера на bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, layout

Возможно ли без использования сторонних библиотек, на bootstrap сделать верстку "без дыр"?

Вот так не должно быть:

[image: это то что у меня получилось а bootstrap сделать блок]

А вот примерно так должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, саму разметку, которая у вас не получается.

Comment: Без сторонних библиотек вы это не сделаете. Вам нужна библиотека Masonry.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yTzksbNCcQ - это подробно

Answer (score 0):

Без сторонних библиотек тут никак, попробуй [Mosonry](http://wp-kama.ru/id_2818/masonry-vyivod-html-blokov-v-vide-kirpichnoy-kladki.html)